# Bash script calls python script that wants interactively input ( not only arguments )

Tags: bash, shell-script, interactive

I have a bash script `bash.sh` that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/local/sbin/pythonScript.py firstArgument secondArgument
```

If I call the pythonScript.py from my terminal with the two command line arguments it asks me the question `" Do you really want to accept this arguments ? ( yes / no )"` and I have to type yes or no and press enter in the terminal in order to resume the script execution.

Now I want that my `bash.sh` script is doing the `yes` answer for me but I have no clue how.

I tried something like this in my script `bash.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "yes\n" | /usr/local/sbin/pythonScript.py firstArgument secondArgument
```

Can anyone help me how to provide dynamic command line arguments to a python script and also simulate the ENTER key press.

EDIT:

The python script is reading from `On Unix, the prompt is written to the file-like object stream. stream defaults to the controlling terminal (/dev/tty)`

Comment: `echo "yes"` (no `\n`) will send the string `yes` followed by a newline.  This will work unless the Python code is reading directly from the TTY (i.e. not from standard input). Does this not work for you?

Comment: And `echo "yes\n"` from Bash will output the literal string `yes\n` (followed by a newline), which may not be what your python program expects.

Comment: Maybe it's not exact answer for your question but please take a look at `expect`. It's a tool for the cases like yours.

Comment: You can also try `echo -e "yes\n"`